# Unix & Linux... together?

Tags: discussion

If unix and linux are supposed to be so different, why are they sharing a category on this web site? This pairing of two OS on one stackexchange topic makes it seem that they are indistinguishable and a question concerning Linux can apply to Unix.

Comment: Linux is a Unix-like operating system. There are many many similarities between the two, many solutions will apply equally to both.

Comment: Just because *some* questions can be relevant to both Unix and Linux, doesn't mean *all* questions about one apply equally to the other. I think it's clear that there is a lot of overlap.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix

Answer (score 8):

`Unix` is not an operating system, it's a family of operating systems. Linux is not an operating system, it's the kernel found in a number of Unix-like and non-Unix-like operating systems.

There's as much difference between one non-Linux-based Unix system and the next as between one Linux-based one and the next, but they all share very similar interfaces and have a lot concepts in common.

It makes sense to have both. I find the *Unix & Linux* name confusing and misleading myself though because it mixes operating systems and kernels and seem to imply that things like GNU would be off-topic and that your TV, printer or smart phone running Linux would be on-topic. `Unix-like operating systems` would have been a better name IMO.

I suppose the name was chosen because few people suspect Debian or Fedora for instance are Unix-like operating systems, while more may have heard that they are built around a Linux kernel (though for Debian, Linux is not the only supported kernel).

Comment: Kernel Panic would have been the best name IMO, but then they stopped doing fancy names.

Comment: Or we could have called it Largely compliant with POSIX operating systems and software that will run in that environment

Comment: UNIX is an operating system, originally from AT&T Bell Laboratories, later sold to Novell. Wikipedia a [history of Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix) that explains fairly well.

Comment: Name was probably also chosen to get those sweet, sweet search engine clicks. Pragmatic.

Answer (score 8):

The name is a useful reminder that GNU/Linux is not the only unix-like environment around and that, unless a particular flavour of unix or particular Linux distribution is mentioned in the question, answers should be careful to at least make note of any non-POSIX features used in the answer or provide both POSIX and non-POSIX versions of the answer.

e.g. if your answer includes a shell script that uses features only available in bash, then mention that it is a `bash` script, not a `sh` script.  Similarly, if you use features of `sed` or `grep` or some other tool that are only available in the GNU versions of that tool, then mention it.  Bonus points for providing a variation of your answer that works using only POSIX features of the tool(s).

Answer (score 2):

GNU/Linux is a UNIX clone. UNIX is a big family and consist other family such as BSD, systemV, SVR and so on. for more information you can visit: [unix history](http://www.levenez.com/unix/)

Comment: note: GNU's Not UNIX! also, what is SVR?